# Verilog data input

Tags: analog, xilinx, input

Hello I am relatively new to verilog and need help on part of a project am working on. I need someone to guide me as to how you read data from an analog device.  I bought an analog temperature sensor from sparkfun and am trying to read data from it. I can not seem to find any examples of getting input. I am using a Nexys3. Any help would be appreciated. This is all I can come up with. I have assigned my ioport to a pin in the constraints file.

Thank you

```
module TempSensor(
    input wire clk,
    input wire reset,
    inout ioport
   );

reg tempV[7:0], tempC[7:0];


always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        tempV <= ioport;        
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Verilog is not working with analog signals.

Comment: Based on the responses so far, the analog sensor would be much harder to use on the nexys3 for a beginner in Verilog. My question is would you recommend the one wire digital temperature sensor provided by sparkfun because it would save me the trouble of trying to build an ADC.
Here is the link to the sensor in question.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/245
Thank you any help would be appreciated. Can not seem to find any examples for nexys3 board

Comment: In this case you might also want to consider accepting an answer if one was helpful and posting a new question. Changing this question from using an analog sensor to a specific 1-wire device would invalidate most of the existing answers to some degree. You might want to leave the new question somewhat open in regard to digital sensors (but include that as an example), the 1-wire protocol is relatively complex and you might be better with some sort of temperature to frequency arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use op amps and a couple of resistors to build a digital to analog converter based on a R-2R ladder as in the attached picture (from Google images as illustration), and compare that ouput with your signal using another opamp.
[image]

(The 74H would be your microprocessor instead, and the comparator DAC-signal is not shown here)

Start with 0 on the DAC, if the comparison gives you DAC < signal then increase it to Vcc (11111111 for a 8bits DAC); then if the comparison gives you DAC > signal decrease it to Vcc/2 (01111111), then if the comparison is DAC < signal to Vcc*0.75 etc. etc. This is called converging via dichotomy, but there are other algorithms based on the same hardware (increasing the DAC until the comparison changes sign for example).

By the way, there is a variant of Verilog which is for analog systems (Verilog A) but it won't do what you expect - the equivalent of analogRead() from an arduino. Verilog is made initially to synthesize gates, so your behavioural model can only easily interact with analog signals through ADCs with digital interfaces regardless of their actual working principle (counting, DAC dichotomy, Delta Sigma...).

You can easily find integrated chips that will spare you the trouble of designing your own ADC, for example the very basic [TLC0820ACN](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/tlc0820acn/ic-8bit-adc-392ksps-pdip20-820/dp/8453691). Parallel output and not differential, single channel, 8bits, big package... Can't be much simpler than that.

Comment: Thanks for finding a picture that has the same op-amp as I suggested! :D :D :D

Comment: Yeaahh. That was made on purpose... Obviously ;)

Comment: The R2R method is a nice example of methodology in the whole analog-digital paradigm. I'm not against the idea of using R2R, there's just a couple of downsides I would like to point out. It uses many pins (1 per bit) and as you increase the number of bits it becomes inaccurate quite quickly because of the differences of resistances in the resistors.  Note that my charge integrator method is very similar to the R2R method; in the FPGA both have an up-running counter whose value is taken when an analog comparison occurs. 

Some trivia: The integrator method, linearized, is used in multimeters.

Comment: That's why i chose to present this solution, not because it was the best one. After all chances were the OP would go for an integrated IC like most people. Just easier to grasp and complementary to your answer. Still, those points are worth raising though, if anything for curiosity's sake so thanks

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any analog inputs in that Nexys3 board, so you'd have to use an analog-to-digital converter to get the data from that temperature sensor. Or you could use a temperature sensor that has a digital output.

There's also several ways to *build* an analog-to-digital converter that would be suitable to your project, but as you say that you're a beginner, it might be easiest to use parts that are readily available. But if you're keen to try some analog design, it's not very difficult to design a circuit where you first discharge a capacitor and then let it charge *through* the analog temperature sensor, which in this case should be a NTC (or PTC) temperature sensitive resistor. Then you could have a running counter in your FPGA and measure the time it takes for the capacitor to charge - that varies with temperature.

For best results, you could use an analog comparator such as LM358 to detect the time when the capacitor is sufficiently charged. But that may not be necessary. You can hook it also, through a short circuit protection resistor, directly to an input pin on the FPGA, but the results may not be the most accurate. And don't connect a capacitor directly to I/O pins without using a resistor in between - the rush currents charging and discharging the capacitor very quickly can stress the FPGA pin beyond their limits, quickly aging the chip (it happened to me).

Sorry if I'm getting overly complicated.

---

[Edit] I took a shot at this "Circuit Lab" thingy to illustrate what I'm talking about in paragraphs 2 and 3. The schematic shows a possible connection that uses 2 pins of the FPGA. It's not minimal, but it's easy to do. R1 and R3 are there really just to protect the FPGA pin drivers, even if the FPGA is misconfigured so that there's no way you can burn the drivers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6a3U9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can discharge the capacitor by setting the CHARGE/DISCHARGE output to "0" for a long enough time (10...100 milliseconds). (For more robust operation, you could also switch the MEASURE pin to output and pull it to "0" at this point) Then charge the capacitor by setting the CHARGE/DISCHARGE output to "1". Use the MEASURE input to detect when it switches from "0" to "1". Use a binary counter to measure the time. Decrease the capacitance to make the charge/discharge time faster.

Anyone, please edit the schematic and/or write Verilog code that would work with this idea.